# How to move down the display of presentation view in iOS

Tags: ios, image, modal-dialog

I'm working on an iOS app which has a couple of non-modal views and a couple of modal views. The non-modal views have a navigation bar at the top, while the modal ones don't. The problem is that there's a common background image for both types. On the modal views, due to the lack of the navigation bar at the top, there's a small gap between the bottom of the image and the bottom of the display.

Here's the code for the opening of a non-modal display:

```
settingsController = [[SettingsController alloc] init]; 

settingsController.appState = appState;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:settingsController animated:YES];

[settingsController release];
```

Here's the code for the opening a modal display:

```
nextLevelViewController = [[[NextLevelViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; 

[self presentModalViewController: nextLevelViewController animated:YES];
```

What's the best way to have the background make up that gap at the bottom of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. It was just a question of modifying the view size to be a bit longer, then stretching the image to match it, in the xlb display editor.